# js issue with if after value becomes 1000

Tags: javascript

Ok so I created a script in order to change the second price (example 2.1) and third price (example 210) of some html input boxes.

[image]

the field ids are the following:

```
first input id = a1  
Second input id = doesn't matter   
Third input id = a2   
Fourth input id = a3
```

The first input is the quantity, the third is the price/unit and the forth is the total price.

It seems to be working fine until `a1 = 1000`. For some reason when this happens a2 price gets the `x=0` and it is like `a1 = 100` until `a1 = 2000` and so on.
I am not sure if what I am saying makes sense.

```js
$qty = {  "0": "100",  "2": "200",  "3": "400",  "4": "600",  "5": "800"};
$price_per_unit = {  "0": "2",  "2": "1.8",  "3": "1.6",  "4": "1.4",  "5": "1.2"};


let arrayppu = Object.values($price_per_unit);
let arrayqti = Object.values($qty);

$("#a1").change(function() {

  let qty = document.getElementById('a1').value;

  for (let x = 0; x < arrayqti.length; x++) {
    if (qty === arrayqti[x] || qty > arrayqti[x]) {
      document.getElementById('a2').value = arrayppu[x];
      document.getElementById('a3').value = (qty * arrayppu[x]).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a1" step='100' />A1<br>
<input type="text" id="a2" />A2<br>
<input type="text" id="a3" />A3<br>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet  - what is expected output and what is actual output that you are unhappy about?

Comment: Ok check the snip now just up until you reach 1000 I edited it to have the correct values and added a step 100. When you reach 1000 a2 = 2 instead of remaining 1.2 @mplungjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your qty to be INTS and not STRINGS

"800" > "1000"

```js
const arrayqti = [100, 200, 400, 600, 800];
const arrayppu = [2.0, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2];

$("#a1").change(function() {
  const qty = +this.value; // cast to int

  for (let x = 0; x < arrayqti.length; x++) {
    if (qty >= arrayqti[x]) {
      document.getElementById('a2').value = arrayppu[x];
      document.getElementById('a3').value = (qty * arrayppu[x]).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a1" step='100' />A1<br>
<input type="text" id="a2" />A2<br>
<input type="text" id="a3" />A3<br>
```

Perhaps more elegant

```js
const arrayqti = [100, 200, 400, 600, 800];
const arrayppu = [2.0, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2];

$("#a1").change(function() {
  const qty = +this.value; // cast to int
  const qti = arrayqti.filter(qti => qty >= qti).pop(); // highest 
  const ppu = arrayppu[arrayqti.indexOf(qti)]
  document.getElementById('a2').value = ppu;
  document.getElementById('a3').value = (qty * ppu).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a1" step='100' />A1<br>
<input type="text" id="a2" />A2<br>
<input type="text" id="a3" />A3<br>
```

Comment: I added a prettier version